# How to remove FRM-40401 when inserting values to table in Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I can't seem to display the message after inserting a value into the table.

It keeps on displaying `FRM-40401` instead

```
 CREATE TABLE NUMBERS
 (
 NUM1 INT
 );
```

While my code for the `WHEN_BUTTON_PRESSED` is

```
 DECLARE
   VAR_VALUE INT;
 BEGIN
   VAR_VALUE := :MYNUMBERS.MYVALUE;

   INSERT INTO NUMBERS (NUM1) VALUES (VAR_VALUE);   

   MESSAGE('YOU INSERTED '||var_value);
   commit;
 END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a commit issued, `FRM-40400` or `FRM-40401` may arise to show transaction occured or no problem raised during transaction, respectively.

To suppress such type of messages, two methods may be considered ;

1. the following may be put in `ON-MESSAGE` trigger at the form level :

   ```
   If  Message_Code in (40400, 40401) Then 
        null;  
   End If;
   ```
2. Alternatively the following may be put inside the trigger where
   commit issued

   ( may be inside a `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger ) :

   ```
   :system.message_level := '5'; 
   -- to suppress all messages with severity below level 5.
    commit;
   :system.message_level := '0';
   ```

   Where *message levels* are :

   ```
   0  - Default value. All types of messages from the other levels of severity. 
   5  - Reaffirms an obvious condition. 
   10 - Indicates that the operator has made a procedural mistake. 
   15 - Declares that the operator is attempting to perform a function 
        for which the form is not designed. 
   20 - Indicates a condition where the operator cannot continue an intended 
        action due to a problem with a trigger or another outstanding condition. 
   25 - Indicates a condition that could result in the form performing incorrectly.
   ```

Answer (score 1):

> I can't seem to display the message after inserting a value into the
>   table. It keeps on displaying ORA40401 instead

This is because of

```
MESSAGE('YOU INSERTED '||var_value);
commit;
```

If you run the form in debug mode, you'd see that message actually **is** displayed at the bottom of the screen, but `commit` - which follows - immediately overwrites the previous message.

The simplest way to "fix" it is to display a message in a manner of an alert, i.e. a pop-up window on the screen, and that can be done by two subsequent `MESSAGE` calls:

```
MESSAGE('YOU INSERTED '||var_value);
MESSAGE('YOU INSERTED '||var_value);
commit;
```

By the way, you don't need a local variable; insert the item value instead:

```
INSERT INTO NUMBERS (NUM1) VALUES (:MYNUMBERS.MYVALUE);
```